# Can't run pgRouting Layer plugin in QGIS 3.10.3

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

I was able to use osm2pgrouting tool successfully on Windows with PostgreSQL version 11.9 and pgRouting version 3.1.0. I successfully generated my "ways" file in a PostGIS conection in QGIS 3.10.3.Now I want to test a Dijkstra algorithm with the pgRouting Layer plugin, but I constantly get a Python error, as follows:

```
File "C:/Users/jorge/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\pgRoutingLayer\pgRoutingLayer.py", line 1255, in openHelp
          db = self.actionsDb[dbname].connect()
         KeyError: ''
```

I am already connected to my postgres DB through DB Manager of QGIS but in my pgRouting Layer dialogue box, I am never "shown as connected" to my postgres DB as shown in following figure. I tried to press refresh button and drop down list many times but no use. I've also saved my user and password in my DB connection, but it haven't solved my problem.

[image]

Comment: All your software versions look very much outdated, many of them not supported anymore. I would strongly suggest you to first try newer versions!

Comment: With what user are you trying to connect?

Comment: @lman the user I tried to connect is "postgres"

Comment: @dkastl I'm sorry, I misspelled the versions. My postgis version is 3.0.2 and my pgrouting version is 3.1.0. My PostgreSQL version is 11.9

Comment: As per the [help/on-topic] it is OK to try and reproduce software problems in a Q&A here, but if you think this is a bug then be sure to submit it to the pgRoutingLayer development team. Please post a link to the bug report here.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue at my end.
System Specification: Ubuntu 18.04, QGIS version - 3.14.16-Pi, Installed pgRouting Layer plugin version - 3.0.0

Now, after installing the latest [release](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgRoutingLayer/releases/tag/v3.0.1) (3.0.1) of pgRouting Layer Plugin, it is working perfectly. I am also able to execute and visualize the resulting layer obtained by [pgr_dijkstraCost](https://workshop.pgrouting.org/2.6/en/chapters/shortest_path.html#exercise-5-many-pedestrians-going-to-different-destinations-returning-aggregate-costs) function.

How I installed pgRouting Layer plugin's v3.0.1?

1. Download [zip](https://github.com/pgRouting/pgRoutingLayer/releases/tag/v3.0.1) for the 3.0.1 release.
2. Select 'Install from ZIP' option followed by selecting downloaded ZIP file under 'Manage and Install Plugin' in QGIS.
3. Restarting pgRouting Layer plugin from 'Database' tab.

Hope this helps!